# How do i get data of a row with MAX(field) for each unique id

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I have one table `GameData`

```
--id(primary)--playTime--gameId--score--userId(foreign)
   1             100       1      50     asd
   2             150       1      100    asd
   3             200       2      150    asd
   4             200       2      40     qwe
   5             100       1      60     qwe
   6             90        1      30     qwe
   7             180       2      10     qwe
```

Given `userId` i want to get rows with **highest playTime for each unique gameId**.

For example if userId is = `"asd"` query should return:

```
[
{playTime:150,gameId:1,score:100},{playTime:200,gameId:2,score:150}


]
```

if userId is = `"qwe"` query should return:

```
   [
    {playTime:100,gameId:1,score:60},{playTime:200,gameId:2,score:40}


    ]
```

This is what i tried but it doenst give desired result:

```
 "SELECT GameData.score,MAX(GameData.playTime) as playTime,GameData.gameId FROM GameDataWHERE GameData.userId=? GROUP BY GameData.gameId"
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT GD.playTime, GD.gameId, GD.score
FROM (SELECT MAX(playTime) playTime, gameId
      FROM GameData
      WHERE userId = 'qwe'   -- Or asd
      GROUP BY gameId) M_ID
JOIN GameData GD ON M_ID.playTime = GD.playTime
                 AND M_ID.gameId = GD.gameId
```